# tensorflow parallelize training in 1 computer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have a computer with one cuda enabled gpu and one 8 core cpu. I'm trying to implement the A3C algorithm for reinforcement learning, which parallelizes the graph and the training environment and syncs the gradient updates to a global graph.

I'm trying to use the distributed tensorflow api to do this:

```
    # Hyperparameter definition
############################################################
epochs = 100000  # Global steps
t_max = 1000  # Thread steps
max_grad_norm = 0.5
alpha = 0.99
gamma = 0.99
#############################################################

ckpt_path = 'ckpt/checkpoints'
log_path = 'logs'


def test(ac, load_path, sess):
    ac.load(load_path)
    env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')

    while True:
        obs = env.reset()
        state_c, state_h = ac.init_lstm_c, ac.init_lstm_h
        done = False
        while not done:
            action, _, state_c, state_h = ac.step(sess, obs, state_c, state_h)
            obs, _, done, _ = env.step(action)


def train(n_epochs, t_max, gamma, ac, sess):
    env = gym.make("Breakout-v0")
    save_dir = os.path.join(log_path)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(save_dir)
    for ep in range(n_epochs):
        ep_obs, ep_disc_rew, m_rew, ep_act, ep_vals, state_c, state_h = process_episode(sess, ac, env, t_max, gamma)
        log = ac.learn(sess, ep_obs, state_c, state_h, ep_disc_rew, m_rew, ep_act, ep_vals)
        step = tf.train.get_global_step().eval(session=sess)
        writer.add_summary(log, global_step=step)


def process_episode(sess, ac, env, t_max, gamma):
    ep_observations, ep_rewards, ep_actions, ep_values = [], [], [], []
    done = False
    t = 0
    observation = env.reset()
    state_c, state_h = ac.c_init, ac.h_init

    while t < t_max and not done:
        action, value, state_c, state_h = ac.step(sess, observation, state_c, state_h)
        ep_observations.append(observation)
        ep_values.append(value)
        ep_actions.append(action)
        observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        ep_rewards.append(reward)
    ep_disc_rewards = discount_rewards(ep_rewards, gamma)
    t_rew = np.sum(ep_rewards)
    return ep_observations, ep_disc_rewards, t_rew, ep_actions, ep_values, state_c, state_h


if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()
    gs = tf.train.create_global_step(tf.get_default_graph())
    env = gym.make("Breakout-v0")
    ac = ActorCritic(env.observation_space, env.action_space)
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
            master=server.target, checkpoint_dir=ckpt_path, save_summaries_steps=None, config=config) as sess:
        train(epochs, t_max, gamma, ac, sess)
    sess.stop()
```

What I want to know is:
- is the code inside the MonitoredTrainingSession block being parallelised across some number of workers?
- is my graph being replicated among x workers?

If not, how can I do that?